# Get a list of versions of all docker compose dependencies?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Can I get a list of all docker compose images/etc that are used in the current env, along with a way to import/fetch those versions, so that my coworker (or future me) can be sure they are using the same exact versions when debugging?

Answer (score 0):

try following commands to get the desired list.

```
#>docker-compose pull
#>docker-compose images
Container   Repository   Tag   Image Id   Size
----------------------------------------------
```

Verify image-id on both machines.